# How to check if covariates in multiple regression is explaining the same?

Tags: regression, validation, information-theory, elastic-net

I am a master's student doing my thesis at the moment and have come to the point of  determining my empirical setup. I would like to get some guidance, in terms of what I am thinking is proper..

1. I set up the following model: $y = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + \ldots + x_{10}$. Here, some of the independent variables can be thought of as belonging in a "group", i.e., some will be proxies for a firm's growth prospectives, risk profile and profitability. I run an elastic net for feature selection, to check if the variables are actually relevant in explaining deviation in $y$.
2. Hereafter, I want to make sure that if two variables in a group, "growth" for example are selected by the model, does not contain the same information. In other words, if they contain the same information --> then I might as well exclude it. But my issue is, how do I go about this? I have never done this before and would like to know if this is possible..

Comment: What do you mean "same information"? How do you define that? High correlation?

Comment: Well, that is the thing... I am not really sure how to define it. Let's say I have two accounting measures (scaled as a % of something else) and the Elastic Net chooses these variables because they are significant in explaining my y. Now, given the way accounting measures are all "interconnected", I want to be sure that the two covariates are not capturing the same changes in my y. 

I hope this helps the understanding of my inquiry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that's exactly what an Elastic Net is doing (in part). The Elastic Net penalty uses both the LASSO and RIDGE penalty, meaning you will both shrink highly correlated coefficients and select only a subset of all the variables (removing redundant variables). If you want to be really sure that your model selects only the most important variables then I would suggest using a LASSO penalty only. This will remove all unnecessary variables and keep only one variable from a set of highly correlated variables.

Comment: Okay, one thing I would be afraid of, was that it penalizes correlated variables (which accounting variables are by nature, i.e. if the EBITDA-margin goes up, the EBIT-margin also goes up) even though they might carry different information. Is this something you think will become an issue?

Comment: @Philip Well if they are highly correlated then they carry similar information so you don't necessarily need both variables, the loss should be minimal. Nevertheless, if you would like to keep some variables which "belong" together (based on your domain knowledge) then you can use various derivations such as the GROUP LASSO, where you can group variables beforehand.